# version check not working with executeUpdate

Tags: hibernate

I am facing following issue with version(Optimistic lock).
    the version check is not happening and exception stale state Exception not thrown when i use below query.
    User details and version no incrementing properly but it is not throwing exception when version no is not equal.

```
try{
Query query= getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("update versioned User u set u.userName=:userName,u.DOB=:DOB where u.userID= :id " );

query.setString("userName", usrName);
query.setString("DOB",dob);
query.executeUpdate()
getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush();
}catch(StaleStateException e){
return "some msg return to notify user "
}
Same thing working fine if use below query.

try{

getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().update(user);
getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush();

}catch(StaleStateException e){
return "some msg return to notify user "
}

any suggestion in this regard will be much helpfull
```

Answer (score 2):

That is expected. What it comes to JPA, bulk updates are not required to update version automatically. In JPA 2.0 specification this is told as follows:

> Bulk update maps directly to a database update operation, bypassing
>   optimistic locking checks. Portable applications must manually update
>   the value of the version column, if desired, and/or manually validate
>   the value of the version column.

Version can be updated in query:

```
u.version = u.version + 1
```

As told in Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct), there is Hibernate specific syntax to achieve same by using VERSIONED keyword:

> In keeping with the EJB3 specification, HQL UPDATE statements, by
>   default, do not effect the Section 5.1.3.1, “Version number” or the
>   Section 5.1.3.2, “Timestamp” property values for the affected
>   entities. However, you can force Hibernate to reset the version or
>   timestamp property values through the use of a versioned update. This
>   is achieved by adding the VERSIONED keyword after the UPDATE keyword.

Comment: We also need a where clause to specify the current version of the row that we are updating (in case it has been updated), to prevent lost update anomaly, thus ensuring data integrity.